# How to disable anti-aliasing only in the terminal?

Tags: terminal

I find the alaised fonts really difficult to read in the terminal. I have been able to disable anti-aliasing across the board by using the ~/.fonts.cnf file. This makes using everything else much less pleasant however.

Please can you tell me how to disable anti-aliasing only in the command prompt?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/32733

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, I suspect the font is different under Rasp pi. Do you know which font it is?

Comment: No, I've never used the default desktop.  However,  last I heard the terminal app there is `lxterminal`, for which there is not a lot of documentation to be found, but it should have some kind of toolbar menu that includes a "Settings" or similar; some terminals have configurable themes that would include the font.  If it isn't there, it may be in some overarching settings app.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334666/how-to-set-change-lxterminal-font-for-standard-user <- Simply changing the font may solve your readability problem.  Another issue with that XML config is that lxterminal may or may not be in the "XTerm family".  You'll have to deep dive on that one...

Comment: OS buster or bullseye or something else?